# How to control the spaces before and after itemize(listing) environment inserted in a table?

Tags: spacing, lists, longtable

I have a macro that inserts itemize environment in a longtable. The issue is that I have big spaces between top and bottom of the itemize environment.

How can I control the spaces?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newcommand{\heu}[1]{%
\textit{BB Heuristic:} #1%
}%

\newcommand{\whypri}[2]{%
\begin{itemize} %
\item \textit{Why}: #1%
\item \textit{Priority Justification}: #2%
\end{itemize}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{c|p{0.4\textwidth}|p{0.5\textwidth}}
\caption[Derivation Plan]{Derivation Plan} \label{d_plan} \\
   \toprule
\textbf{1} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{Goal: Extensibility}} \\\midrule
1.1 
& \heu{Reduce Data/Event Dependency}
&  \whypri{Extensible components should be working as a standalone that has minimum
dependency on other components. The more dependencies, the more complexity
Occurs To prevent extensible structure.}{Less complexity in extension introduced
by reducing dependency.}
\\\midrule
%\st{BB Heuristic: }
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I prefer `enumitem` and use `\setlist{ }` to set `topsep=0pt`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a `minipage`:

```
\newcommand{\whypri}[2]{%
\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
\begin{itemize} %
\item \textit{Why}: #1%
\item \textit{Priority Justification}: #2%
\end{itemize}%
\end{minipage}%
}
```

In addition, I'd also use `enumitem` and apply `leftmargin=*`. The full code will be:

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcommand{\heu}[1]{%
\textit{BB Heuristic:} #1%
}%

\newcommand{\whypri}[2]{%
\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*] %
\item \textit{Why}: #1%
\item \textit{Priority Justification}: #2%
\end{itemize}%
\end{minipage}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{c|p{0.4\textwidth}|p{0.5\textwidth}}
\caption[Derivation Plan]{Derivation Plan} \label{d_plan} \\
   \toprule
\textbf{1} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{Goal: Extensibility}} \\\midrule
1.1
&\raggedright \heu{Reduce Data/Event Dependency}
&  \whypri{Extensible components should be working as a standalone that has minimum
dependency on other components. The more dependencies, the more complexity
Occurs To prevent extensible structure.}{Less complexity in extension introduced
by reducing dependency.}
\\\midrule
%\st{BB Heuristic: }
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

And I'd also remove vertical lines and use `l` for first column.

```
\begin{longtable}{lp{0.4\textwidth}p{0.5\textwidth}}
```

[image]